# Database in Boundary Control Entity UML Class Diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Should I represent the database details in my class diagram as separate classes or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you model entities you don't care about a physical database. It's just implicit that entities are stored in databases. When you refine your design and derive concrete database objects you will eventually make them inherit from a `Serializable` or the like to make them persistent on a concrete database. Or you relate them to tables which you create as part of a database instance.